# Wordpress change li class name without walker?

Tags: php, wordpress, css, class

Is there any possible way in wordpress to change the class of "li" to `wp_nav_menu()` without using Walker?

```
'sub-menu' => 'dropdown',
```

I tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
<?php
$args = array('theme_location' => 'navigate',
                'container' => '',
                'container_class' => 'none',
                'menu_class' => 'nav middle navbar-nav',
                'menu_id' => 'none',
                'sub-menu' => 'dropdown',
    );

wp_nav_menu( $args );

?>
```

I need a simple solution, just not to use Walker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the class name of the ul inside the li try this one.
Put this code your theme's functions.php file

function change_submenu_class_name($submenu) {

$submenu = preg_replace('/ class="sub-menu"/','/ class="dropdown" /',$submenu);

return $submenu;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu','change_submenu_class_name');

OR if you want to add class to li you can do this from admin, just login to admin and follow the step:
go to Appearance-> Menu and do the process 
http://prntscr.com/f98s4v

If you have any question please let me know.

Comment: Yup lol, the last thing I can do is this, it means on `function.php` this is the last thing i can do. So thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome :)
If you have any question please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

There's a hook you can use to change the classes on a menu's `<li>` elements: `nav_menu_css_class`.

Your question doesn't state exactly what you're trying to do with the 'dropdown' class. In my example I'm adding the 'dropdown' class to nested menu items.

```
/**
 * Modify the classes applied to menu items in the 'navigate' menu.
 *
 * @param array    $classes The CSS classes that are applied to the menu item's `<li>` element.
 * @param WP_Post  $item    The current menu item.
 * @param stdClass $args    An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
 * @param int      $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
 *
 * @return array 
 */
function wpse_modify_nav_menu_item_classes( $classes, $item, $args, $depth ) {

    // Only apply changes to the correct menu, 'navigate',
    if ( 'navigate' !== $args->theme_location ) {
        return $classes;
    }

    // Modify menu li classes here...
    // Add 'dropdown' class to nested menu items.
    if ( 1 <= $depth ) {
        $classes[] = 'dropdown';
    } 

    // We're using a filter so don't forget to return.
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'wpse_modify_nav_menu_item_classes', 10, 4 );
```